# Stretching tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

[image]

I need to stretch `.v-tabs-cont`. Image perfectly describes my intentions.

I don't want to stretch whole div.col only the `v-tabs-cont` height to `.vtabs` height.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tse4/7/)

**Temporary solution:**

$("div.v-tabs-cont").css("min-height", $("ul.vtabs").height() + "px");

But I'm still looking for a CSS solution, just to my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

remove `float:left` from `.v-tabs-cont`

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tse4/5/)

Comment: It has to be 150px. And look at the height it's not 100%

Comment: I really appreciate that but I don't want to stretch whole `div.col` only the `v-tabs-cont` to `.vtabs` height.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

You can set the height and margin of your elements :

For instance, give a `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to the ul :

```
ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Give a height to your `li` elements

```
li {
  height: 30px;
}
```

Then set your right panel's height is the sum of `margin-top` + `margin-bottom` + `num_li` * `li_height` = 10px + 10px + 4 * 30px = 140px

Then you just have to tell the right panel content not to overflow with `overflow: scroll` for instance

```
.v-tabs-cont {
  height: 140px;
  overflow: scroll
}
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tse4/8/) (I put my css additions at the bottom of the css section for clarity)

**Option 2:**

If you cannot set the margin/height of your elements, or if you have a variable number of list elements, follow the same logic to compute the right panel height on page load (using jQuery)

```
var height = $('.vtabs li:first').height() * $('.vtabs li').length 
              + parseInt($('.vtabs').css('marginTop').replace('px', '')) 
              + parseInt($('.vtabs').css('marginBottom').replace('px', ''));
$('.v-tabs-cont').css('height', height + 'px');
```

You still need to add the `overflow: scroll` to prevent the content from overflowing

```
.v-tabs-cont {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tse4/10/)

Comment: Thanks for your time but this is not what I'm looking for. I need a flexible solution. This will be a shortcode in wordpress so there is no specified number of tabs.

Comment: I don't want a scroll because it looks horrible with my style. jQuery would be the easiest solution but I believe there is a way to make it with pure CSS.

Comment: @MackoTarana You can replace `overflow: scroll` by `overflow: hidden` for instance ([overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp))

Comment: This will hide the content and borders in my styled tabs.

Comment: Then just don't set the `overflow` property or set it to `overflow: visible` :)

Comment: If you went one step further with my answer, then accept it and maybe ask a new question concerning the new problems you are facing.

Or edit your question to provide all your requirements (including the styling of your tabs)

Comment: Sorry I'm not satisfied with this answer but I really appreciate your advice. +1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42084/discussion-between-aurelien-gasser-and-macko-tarana)